# Primefaces - <p:spinner> up and down buttons

Tags: primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.4.1.

Whenever `<p:spinner>`'s up or down buttons are pressed, I need to know whether up button or down button is pressed. 
How can I get it from Java side? Is there any event activated?

Thanks.